# Is there a way to change grid placement with media query?

Tags: css

I placed the element horizontally using gird and I want to change it vertically. However, I would like to use the media query to change it to portrait when the page size is reduced. Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: There is a way. What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to do something like:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

Check this code-sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-almeida-fvwgm7?file=/src/styles.css